# Indegree resulted by Multigraph

Tags: graph

From my understanding Multigraph is rare in CS. But they do exist. So if one vertex(A) points to another vertex(C) twice, does that mean vertex C has an indegree of 2?

Answer (score 0):

Multigraphs, just like digraphs, have both an indegree and an outdegree, and that those don't necessarily have to be equal.

In a multigraph you have parallel edges, but you could also have a complex graph with both parallel and single old fashioned edges connecting some nodes.
Note that if the multigraph in question has loops, that also adds to the indegree and outdegree.

And no, I don't think this is a rare thing in CS. There's plenty of relationships (particularly in social modelling) that are parallel and not equivalent.

Consider this example, an example of the most basic multigraph, with two nodes and a parallel edge.

```
( 
  Nodes: Alice 'A', Bob 'B', 
  relationship edge C'1 A --- wife of --> B,
  relationship edge C'2 B --- husband of --> A
)
```